# Diophantine equation in $a, b, c,$and $d$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm looking for positive integers $a, b, c,$ and $d$ such that
$$ (ad - bc)(ac + bd) \: | \: abcd$$

One partial solution that I found is
$$(a, \, b, \, c, \, d) = (2x + 1,\, 2x, \, 2x + 2, \, 2x + 1)$$

Are there other partial solutions?

Another way of looking at this problem is that I am trying to find positive integers $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ such that $(A-B)(C+D) | N$ where $AB=CD=N$. This is, in fact, equivalent to $A=ad, B=dc, C=ac,$ and $D=bd$.

One direction I went is this.

There must be some positive integer P such that
\begin{align*}
   A - B &= \frac{N}{P}\\
   A - B &= \frac{AB}{P}\\
   \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{A} &= \frac{1}{P}\\
   \frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{P} &= \frac{1}{B}
\end{align*}

It follows that, for some integers $r, s,$ and $t$
$$ A = r(r + s)t $$
$$ P = s(r + s)t $$
$$ B = rst $$
$$ A-B = r^2t$$
$$ N = r^2s(r+s)t^2$$

Similarly, there must be some positive integer Q such that
\begin{align*}
   C + D &= \frac{N}{Q}\\
   D + C &= \frac{CD}{Q}\\
   \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} &= \frac{1}{Q}
\end{align*}

It follows that, for some integers $u, v,$ and $w$
$$ C = u(u + v)w $$
$$ D = v(u + v)w $$
$$ Q = uvw $$
$$ C+D = (u+v)^2w$$
$$ N = uv(u+v)^2w^2$$

The requirement that $(A-B)(C+D) | N$ can be expressed as
$r^2t(u+v)^2w | uv(u+v)^2w^2$
which simplifies to
$$ r^2t | uvw $$

It looks so suggestive. But I haven't found anything useful yet.

Another thing I noticed is that
$$(A - B)^2 + (C + D)^2 = (A + B)^2 + (C - D)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D^2$$

which is very pretty but doesn't seem to help any.

Comment: Let's say that a triangle with sides of lengths $x, y$ and $\frac{1}{n}$, where $x$ and $y$ are rational and $n$ is an integer, is pointy if the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{n}$. It turns out that a triangle is pointy if, for some rational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $(x, y, \frac{1}{n}) =  \left(\alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha}, \, \beta + \frac{1}{\beta}, \, \alpha - \frac{1}{\alpha} - \beta + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)$

Comment: Letting $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ and $\beta = \frac{c}{d}$, you end up with the above Diophantine equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can enlarge your solution space to 
$$
(a,b,c,d) = (sn, s(n+1), t(n-1), tn) \text{ and}\\ 
(a,b,c,d) = (sn, s(n-1), t(n+1), tn) \\
$$
with $s, t, n \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $n$ odd.

Your solution corresponds to the second of these, identifying $n = 2x+1, s = t=1$.

(Steven Gregory pointed out by an improvement that the cooefficient in $c$ and $d$, which is now called $t$, can be different than $s$.)

But this is still probably not an exhaustive set of solutions.