# Pointy triangles exists

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

In Yahoo Answers,
[here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120207131059AAdxE4z),
Rita the dog defined a pointy triangle, (more or less) as having three properties.

1. The lengths of two sides are rational and greater than 1.
2. The length of the third side is 1/n for some integer n.
3. The area of the triangle is 1/n.

   We say that a pointy triangle likes n if its area is 1/n.

Prove that pointy triangles like an infinite number of n's.

As Pauley Morph, I posted the same question in Yahoo Answers,
[here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150505060140AAJzO10), and got no response.
I also posted the right triangle lemma,
[here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150220072820AAU5xPh), and got one tepid answer.

Comment: Why all the negative votes?

Comment: I think it's interesting that your question got downvoted but your answer got upvoted.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I checked and SE said I could answer my own questions. So I did. I spent (well, actually, enjoyed) a lot of time working on this problem and tried several approaches that led me nowhere. I was staring at a table of solutions and decided to try $\alpha \beta = u/v$. When the Pells equations popped up, I got that rush that I always get at at such Eurika moments. It would be nice if the down votes were accompanied by comments.

Comment: Yeah it's a perfectly fine thing to do. I'm just intrigued by the fact that people like the answer, but not the question. It's unusual.

Comment: The two right triangles in the picture below are $(5, 12, 13)$ and $(7, 24, 25)$ right triangles scaled down to $(5/6, 2, 13/6)$ and $(7/12, 2, 25/12)$. Corresponding to $\alpha = 3/2$ and $\beta = 4/3$.In this case, 
$(\alpha - \dfrac{1}{\alpha}) - (\beta - \dfrac{1}{\beta}) = 1/4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: parameterizing a pointy triangle]

Clearly the altitude at the base with length $1/n$ is $2$. It can be shown, if any right triangle has one side of length 2, then there is a real number $\gamma > 1$ such that the other side has a lenght of $\gamma - \dfrac{1}{\gamma}$ and a hypotenuse of length  $\gamma + \dfrac{1}{\gamma}$. Also the lengths are all rational if and only if $\gamma$ is rational. Using the image above, we must find rational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation}
   (\alpha - \dfrac{1}{\alpha}) - (\beta - \dfrac{1}{\beta}) = \dfrac 1 n
\end{equation}
for some integer n.

We suppose that there are positive, relatively prime, odd integers u > v such that $\alpha \beta = \dfrac{u}{v}$. It is perfectly fine for one of u or v to be even, but the equations have to be changed slightly. Since I don't need to find all pointy triangles, I won't add that complication to the solution. Replacing $n$ with $u v k$, $\beta$ with $\dfrac{u}{v \alpha}$, and simplifying, we wind up with the equation

\begin{equation}
   v(u+v)k\alpha^2 - \alpha - u(u+v)k = 0
\end{equation}

The positive solution is

\begin{align}  
\alpha = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 + 4uv(u+v)^2k^2}+1}{2v(u+v)k}\cr
\beta = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 + 4uv(u+v)^2k^2}-1}{2v(u+v)k}
\end{align}

Clearly $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will exists and be rational if there exists integers $N_k$, that depend on $k$, such that $N_k^2 = 1 + 4uv(u+v)^2k^2$. But these are Pell's equations and such equations are guaranteed to have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Writing $\alpha = a/b$ and $\beta = c/d$ (in lowest terms) we see that a, b, c, and d solve [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173861/diophantine-equation-in-a-b-c-and-d)

Comment: Note also that
$\alpha - \beta = \dfrac{1}{v(u+v)k}$ and
$\dfrac{1}{\alpha} - \dfrac{1}{\beta} = \dfrac{1}{u(u+v)k}$ So
$(\alpha - \dfrac{1}{\alpha}) - (\beta - \dfrac{1}{\beta}) = \dfrac{1}{u v k}$
becomes $\dfrac{1}{u(u+v)k} + \dfrac{1}{v(u+v)k} = \dfrac{1}{u v k}$
which solves 
[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166999/find-all-integers-x-y-and-z-such-that-frac1x-frac1y-frac)